# typescript assert that the inner object is defined

Tags: typescript, types, casting, eslint

I have a resource that I need to convert to the interface A:

```
interface A {
    patientId: string;
    firstName: string;
    initials: string[];
    lastName: string;
   
}
```

Also I have this function

```
public static convert(data: data) {
        return {
            patientId: fhirData.identifier[0].value,
            firstName: fhirData.name[0].given[0],
            initials: fhirData.name[0].given.slice(1),
            lastName: fhirData.name[0].family,
       
        };
    }
```

But eslint throws errors that fhirData.identifier could be undefined. Is there any good solutions to assert that these object are defined or any solutions to fix this error? (I am not allowed to change interface). Would appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: To *assert* as in bypass the type check and potentially unsafely instruct the compiler to accept this code, which can then lead to runtime errors? Or do you just want to safely handle the case where the data *is* undefined? Or are you saying that the typings are wrong and `identifier` can never be undefined?

Comment: @VLAZ hey, sorry for bad explanation, the data can be undefined, how can I handle this without writing billion of if-statements?

Comment: `fhirData.identifier[0].value` -> `fhirData.identifier?.[0]?.value` or if you need to default to some value if you get `undefined` there: `fhirData.identifier?.[0]?.value ?? whateverValueYouWant` Not a single `if` statement.

Comment: @VLAZ yea, that works! post it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

To keep your code reasonably succinct, it's common to use an assertion library.

Node.js has [`assert`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) built-in.

```js
import assert from 'node:assert/strict';

function convertPatient(fhirData: FhirPatient): AeonPatient {
  assert(fhirData.identifier, 'Expected fhirData.identifier');
  // ...
  return {
    patientId: fhirData.identifier[0].value,
    // ...
  };
}
```

Alternatively a library like [`zod`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) is a good option as it allows you to define complex validation rules as well as infer a typescript interface to ensure the validation is in sync with the type.

```js
import { z } from "zod";

const fhirPatient = z.object({
  identifier: z
    .array(
      z.object({
        value: z.string().min(1),
        // ...
      })
    )
  // ...
});
type FhirPatient = z.infer<typeof fhirPatient>;

function convertPatient(fhirData: Partial<FhirPatient>): AeonPatient {
  const parsedFhirData = fhirPatient.parse(fhirData);
  // ...
  return {
    patientId: parsedFhirData.identifier[0].value
  };
}
```

Comment: I think "I got a value I expect can be there but don't like" is hardly a reason to bomb out with an error. Which is what `assert` does. Usually these situations are to be expected and should be able to be handled. Errors are more for when you cannot continue doing anything else - the program is in error state, something completely wrong happened. So you sound the alarms and try to shut everything down. Unless there is a special rescue team that can `catch` this situation and put out the fires so work can continue.

Comment: That's quite the analogy . I guess neither of us can really decide how best to handle this case without wider context but given @icarus mentioned he doesn't want to "write a billion if-statements" I figured he wanted to return the interface as defined but keep TS happy which would require you to throw.